# Draggable div. How to keep position after changing page and reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a draggable menu div for my page.

The menu can switch between different pages. My problem is that when I go to a new page, the menu div jumps back to the original position.

It would be nice if the menu div would stay in the same position that it has been dragged to when a visitor changes pages.

I have found other similar topics around the web but none which corresponds with my script code. What code do I need to ad? And how to do this using local storage?

```
        <script>        
dragElement(document.getElementById(("div_drag")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

        </script>
```

Comment: Just save the position values to local storage or cookies and load them from there on page load/reload with default values fallback

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie for solve it, see it here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp